# How can back shield of JWST be 85-100 degrees Celsius hot if it will be in Earth's shadow?

Tags: lagrangian-points, james-webb-telescope, cooling

I have heard, that back shield of James Webb space telescope will be as hot as 85-100 degrees of Celsius.

But how can it be, if it will be in Earth's shadow in L2?

Comment: Earth's shadow does not reach L2. Indeed, the operation manual for JWST expressly forbids it from entering within Earth or Moon shadow at any time.

Comment: related: [Why is the hot side of the James Webb Space Telescope expected to be 85 C?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56059/12102) and [Why are eclipses of the James Webb by the Earth or Moon not permitted during the mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56047/12102)

Comment: Related:  [What does the Sun-Earth-Moon system look like from the Sun-Earth L-2 point?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10355/what-does-the-sun-earth-moon-system-look-like-from-the-sun-earth-l-2-point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWST will never be in the Earth's shadow, or the moon's shadow.

Reference:
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190028885/downloads/20190028885.pdf